# How to change the styles of Real part and Imaginary part in ReImPlot using ReImStyle?

Tags: plotting, complex

I have following code,

```
ReImPlot[(2 + 3*I)*x + (4 + 5 I), {x, 0, 3}, ReImStyle -> {{Dashed, Red}, {DotDashed, Red}}]
```

This will created the plot that looks like this
[image]

But I want both real and imaginary part to be colored red with Dashed and DotDashed curve respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unusually, Mathematica seems to have an ambiguous definition here.  Normally, a list of directives is treated as a directive.  But in this case, the list is interpreted (I guess) as directives to be applied to separate functions.

You can get round this by explicitly wrapping the directives with `Directive`, thus.

```
ReImPlot[(2 + 3*I)*x + (4 + 5 I), {x, 0, 3}, 
         ReImStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, Red], Directive[DotDashed, Red]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that actually works. However, now I cannot figure out how to put plotlegends? Can you add the plotlegend in the plot of your answer?

Comment: I suggest you ask another question.  I'm going to bed now, but other people may be able to help.

Comment: @sslucifer  `PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.2, .9}]`